# Android, hide toolbar and bootom bar + open them(like gallery)

Tags: java, android

[Bars shown(picture1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlVhq.jpg)
Show

[Bars hidden(picture2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XojzX.jpg)
Hide

Comment: Whats your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide the ui on top and bottom, you can do that by calling `.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` or `.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` on each of the views or the layout containing them. So for example your code could look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final View layout_with_stuff_to_hide = findViewById(R.id.layout);

    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            layout_with_stuff_to_hide.setVisibility(layout_with_stuff_to_hide.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```